# Mount USB flash drive via command line as it would be mounted automatically after the stick pluged in under Linux

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, mount, automount

When you insert a flash stick into USB port the following happens:

1. The file system of each USB drive partition is detected automatically
2. Partitions are mounted automatically to a temporary path like `/media/bob/7B57-DCAA` with proper options
3. The path is owned by currently logged in user (in GUI)
4. The path is deleted automatically after `umount /media/bob/7B57-DCAA` command execution

Is there a simple command which does the same without having to manually create the path, to detect FS type, to mount the partition, to give proper permissions/ownership and to delete the path after `umount`?

**UPDATE**

Currently, I'm using Linux Mint 17 Qiana (Cinnamon) but other distros/window managers are also interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends highly on your window manager. For gnome it is pretty easy and doesn't even need root:

> # gnome-mount /dev/sdxy

Unfortunately, KDE has no helper/wrapper like gnome and invokes udisks directly, which is the way you wanna do it in KDE (root required):

> # sudo udisks --mount /dev/sdxy

EDIT:
gnome-mount is of course highly outdated, as it uses HAL. The new way would be to use gvfs:

> # gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdxy

Comment: any chance you know how it is done in Cinnamon?

Comment: As cinnamon is a fork of gnome, it should work the same way. As I revised in the original post, gnome-mount should be substituted by gvfs-mount nowadays.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: `$gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdxy`        works fine for me on a linuxmint 18.3 KDE Edition.  Thanks! It helps a lot for scripts.

Comment: maybe in KDE u wanna use udisks? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62676/mounting-from-dolphin-vs-commandline

Answer (score 0):

I personally use pmount for this task. You don't have to run it as root either.

```
sudo apt-get install pmount
pmount /dev/sdX
pumount /dev/sdX
```

Just seems to work.

Comment: You might need to add user(s) to the `plugdev` group.